# I can't get value from QCalendarWidget() properly

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm making a calendar based app with Python. For this, I'm using QCalendarWidget() of PyQt5. However, I can't get the selected date properly. When I run the code below, whichever day I clicked, it just prints the today like `PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2019, 3, 30)`. What I want is to get the selected date. How can I solve this?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.setGeometry(50,50,310,300)
window.setWindowTitle("Reminder")
cal = QCalendarWidget(window)
cal.setGridVisible(True)
date = cal.selectedDate()

def get_date():
    print(date)

cal.clicked[QDate].connect(get_date)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you printing? are you printing the variable *date*, and at what moment are you assigning a value to the variable *date*? then at the beginning, and then it is never updated, so the value of *date* is the value that the QCalendarWidget takes at the beginning that is today. The solution is to use the information that carries the signal for it, your slot must have the date parameter

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.setWindowTitle("Reminder")
    cal = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(gridVisible=True)
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(window)
    lay.addWidget(cal)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QDate)
    def get_date(date): # <--- date parameter
        print(date)

    cal.clicked.connect(get_date)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```